# How to set environment variables in JBoss

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, webserver

We are developing an application that is deployed in a JBoss.
we would like to define a properties files like this:

```
URL_DEVELOPMENT.properties = ...
URL_TEST.properties = ...
URL_PRODUCTION.properties = ...
```

and define an environment variable in the JBoss which contains the information about the execution context

```
for example --> ENVIRONMENT = DEVELOPMENT
```

Anyone knows:

1. How to set environment variables in JBoss.
2. How to get these variables from an applicacion deployed in JBoss in runtime execution?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest and most straight forward way is to log into jboss web admin:
*www.yoururl:9990*

Then under configuration, look **for system property.**

At runtime, it is very easy: `System.getProperty(yourPropertyKey)` and the good thing is that a change in any of these properties is reflected immediately at runtime.

The other scenario is to open up **standalone.xml**

```
<server ...>
   <system-properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.archive.factory" value="org.jipijapa.eclipselink.JBossArchiveFactoryImpl"/>
   </system-properties>
</server>
```

The other option is to read on jboss cli and configure system properties from there. (Only useful if you want to work with remote jboss and you cannot ssh into the server, and you cannot access the web admin)